# python more trouble importing modules

Tags: python, python-module, python-import

I asked a similar question yesterday, but have acquired a really odd problem since then.  With this directory structure:

```
app/
    models/
        __init__.py
        user.py
        other.py
    pages/
        __init__.py
        pages.py
```

The models/__init__.py file has this line:

```
__all__ = ['user', 'other']
```

and the pages/__init__.py has

```
__all__ = ['pages']
```

In pages.py, in order to use any of the classes in user.py or other.py, I have to have

```
from models import *
import models
```

at the top, and then I can declare a `User` class like this:

```
my_user = models.user.User()
```

If I exclude either of the import-ing statements at the top, I get errors like

```
"Class user has no attribute User"
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I love Python, but I wish it's import functionality worked more like PHP's.

Comment: It's the first time I've heard someone saying they'd like Python to work like PHP...

Comment: ha, yea it's the first time i've said it too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options, depending on where you want to be explicit and how much you want available "by default" (which also means forced).

In those __init__ files you could use:

```
# models/__init__.py shown:
import user, other                 # ambiguous relative import
from . import user, other          # relative import
from app.models import user, other # absolute import
```

Or, where you would otherwise just have `import models`, use:

```
from models import user, other
# or:
import models.user, models.other
```

The latter form is more widely preferred.

Comment: i put `from app.models import user, other` and it works great, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import models.user
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can be real helpful when you're learning python (or debugging), is to run interactively and use the `dir()` function to see what lives where:

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> import models
>>> dir(models)
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
>>> models.user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'user'
>>> from models import *
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'models', 'other', 'user']
>>> dir(models)
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__','__path__', 'other', 'user']
>>> user
<module 'models.user' from 'C:\test\models\user.py'>
>>> models.user
<module 'models.user' from 'C:\test\models\user.py'>
>>> user.User
<class 'models.user.User'>
```

**Update:** fixed output.

Comment: What is the content of your models/\_\_init\_\_.py?  As the question is stated, `import models; models.user` will give an AttributeError.  (Does your sample have `import user` in models/\_\_init\_\_.py?  That would explain your different results.)

Comment: @Roger - my models/__init__.py is just `__all__ = ['user', 'other']`.

Comment: Then I'd expect you to get what I get: http://codepad.org/yWnKyVAW.  Did you have an earlier `import models.user` or similar?  (That import will modify the models module object.)

Comment: when i just use import models _or_ from models import * and run dir(models) i get "['__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']".  I have to have both of those statements in order for users and other to be included.

Comment: @Roger I see what the problem is now. I had leftovers in the local scope from doing a `from models import *`. Fixed it up.